# React controlling state with an outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

React newbie here,
I have a component for login which has two states (logged and not), and a button, a button click makes a form appear for the user.

```
function Main() {

    const [state, setState] = useState(false);
    function buttonClick(event) {
        state = !state;
    }

    return (
    <div id='main'>
        <p id='main-body'>{lorem}</p>
        { state ? <LoginForm /> : <LoginButton />}
    </div>
 )
}
```

my issue is that the onClick itself (and the button) are in another component:

```
function LoginButton() {
    return (
        <div class="btn-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-centered" onClick={}>Login</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Have I understood the concept wrongly? How do I achieve the result I want with the outside component?
Thanks a lot for any help, I'd VERY appreciate explanations so I can learn.

Comment: You would pass that variable into the child component. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass buttonClick method in login button component like this

```
<LoginButton onClick={buttonClick} />
```

and inside Loginbutton component you can do something like this

```
<button type="button" ... onClick={props.onClick}>Login</button>
```

so when you click login button it will trigger you buttonClick method.

Answer (score 1):

the LoginButton should get props and return a callback to the Main that will switch the state and you should also use useState to change the state in order to change the DOM,

thats how it should look

```
function Main() {

const [state, setState] = useState(false);
function buttonClick(event) {
    setState((prev) => !prev);
}

return (
    <div id='main'>
        <p id='main-body'>{lorem}</p>
        { state ? <LoginForm  /> : <LoginButton callback={buttonClick} />}
    </div>
)

function LoginButton(props) {
    const {callback} = props;
return (
    <div class="btn-centered">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-centered" onClick={callback}>Login</button>
    </div>
)
```

}